# How would I go about creating a recognizer for bills

Tags: model-selection, algorithms

Let say I have various electric bills, I want to get the account number and the payment total, how would you approach such a task?

One of my ideas is to train a model to recognize different possible bills, and once the recognizer sees the bill, it will then look for the location of where the numbers are.  But this approach could fail if the bill changes and will need to be retrained.

Comment: I would begin by considering how the electric bill is given as data.  Do you have scanned images or the original computer representation created by the energy producer, for instance?  But how could anyone possibly plan for indefinite changes in the bill?  That would seem to be tantamount to asking for a comprehensive discussion of all existing ways to address text-recognition or data-extraction problems, which is not something we can handle on this site.

Comment: Ok, what if we can infer that the account number starts with "RR" and can infer that as an account number?

Comment: The issues here is that the OCR will return you everything piece of text on the bill, knowing our target text would be the engineering problem.